# Reverse X axis of touchscreen on Windows 8?

Tags: drivers, windows-8, touchscreen

I have an aftermarket touchscreen that was installed on Windows XP and is now running on Windows 8. For Windows XP I had a driver that only detected mouse input via the touchscreen. Windows 8 does a nice job of detecting finger input as well with the generic driver. However, the X axis input is reverse and I would like to correct this.

How do I do this?

If more information is needed I can try to provide it.

EDIT: I am having trouble. I opened the calibration tool but on touching the area with the crosshair it shows my finger is on the right side of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try calibrating the input device (instructions based on information [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_cp-desktop/is-there-a-way-to-calibrate-the-touch-screen/90885b96-cb24-4e1f-b7f6-1ef805058400?msgId=859fec95-fe0f-440c-974c-2803b80fdc0d) since I do not have a device with a touchscreen):

1. Search for "calibrate" and click the "Settings" filter on the right.
2. Click the option to calibrate the screen for touch input.

Comment: I am having trouble. I opened the calibration tool but on touching the area with the crosshair it shows my finger is on the right side of the screen. What does that mean?

Comment: Hmm... I was hoping the calibration tool would see that and figure out that the x-axis is reversed.

Comment: Would you say it would be best to use the Windows XP drivers and live with the mouse input based touch? Or do you think a fix exists for this?

Comment: @nvdkgm: Personally I would suggest living with mouse-based input, but someone else here might know of a solution.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [pretty similar question for windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/406502/how-can-i-reverse-mouse-movement-x-y-axis-system-wide-win-7-x64) here - I did a few tests (at my own peril) to see what works, and polynomial's mouse inverter from this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/406865/10165) seems to work. [Direct link](http://www.sendspace.com/file/zjuwfv) here. I need to poke around some more to get it to autostart, but start it up, click on the little mouse button on your taskbar, and select which axis to invert.

It supposedly remembers your last settings once started, and you can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>x</kbd> to invert X axis and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>x</kbd> to invert y axis.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work for the touch portion. However it is a handy tool that I have saved. I think that executable was only for a mouse.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my Asus. What I did to fix it was navigate to the Control Panel, click `Hardware and Sound`, then `Tablet PC Settings` and finally `Calibrate`. If you follow the prompt, it should fix this issue.