# Touch screen monitor is reversed

Tags: windows-7, display, touchscreen

I have a DGM L-1935WD touch screen monitor I purchased second hand to use, but when I touch the monitor it comes up as if I am touching somewhere else.

If I click the Windows button on my monitor I shows as if I am clicking the top right hand corner, or if I click the bottom right it shows I am clicking the top left.

I have tried to find drivers (which I haven't found any for it) and also done the tablet PC settings and clicked setup on there which has has no effect.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to sort this?

Comment: it has a VGA cable and usb cable which are both plugged in and im running windows 7 professional 64bit

Comment: Are you sure this monitor is a touch screen monitor as standard, and the touch screen isn't a third party add on, upside down/back to front? I've looked it up and can't find any evidence of a touch screen model?

Comment: im not 100% sure as i bought it second hand but it has a usb cable that is hard wired into the side of it

Comment: Could you post a photo perhaps?

Comment: here is a link to a picture of where the USB cable goes into the side of the monitor [link] (http://s248.photobucket.com/user/craig2d/library/Others)

Comment: Kinda hard to tell much from this - Could you get a picture of the front as well? Are there any other brand names on the front/sides? Any other serial numbers?

Comment: i have added one of the only brand on the front and one of the sticker on the back. also a short video that shows what happens when i touch the screen and where the clicks appear

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the manual for your monitor [here](http://www.digimate.com/download/L-1935WD%20User%20Manual.pdf) - there is no mention at all of a touch screen function, USB, or anything else. As such, I'm suspicious there is a third party overlay on your monitor controlling the touch interface.

Without being able to physically inspect the device, it's hard to say for certain what is providing it. It's possible, looking at your video, that the overlay is fitted upside down, as the input you're describing would make sense if the touch screen was rotated 180<sup>o</sup>.

It's also possible the touch screen is fitted correctly and has an accompanying driver and software package allowing the input to be rotated. Without knowing the exact device, it's not possible for me to say what this may be, but you could do the following steps to try and work it out:

1. Go to Device Manager (Win + X -> Device Manager)
2. Find your touch device in the list - It may be under `Human Interface Devices` or `Mice and other input devices` if it's not in an obvious location.
3. Right click the device and click `Properties`, go to `Details` and click `Hardware Ids` in the drop down box.
4. In here you should see a `VID` and `PID` ID, which you can search online to find out what the device actually is and what driver it takes. For example, my mouse uses `VID_0461 PID_4D17`, so I would search this to find a relevant driver, should I need it.

Alternatively, you could see if the touch overlay can be removed easily and fitted rotated the other way up - although if the previous owner had it this way it's more likely there is a software way this can be resolved.

Edit- Looking around a little more, a couple more suggestions are:

1. Try using the calibration tool (See [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/touch-pen-settings-faq#) for more info,
2. There's a Q/A [here](https://superuser.com/questions/406502/how-can-i-reverse-mouse-movement-x-y-axis-system-wide-win-7-x64) where one user has created a tool to flip the X and Y axis of a mouse, although this is likely to disrupt your normal mouse usage as well.

Comment: do you have a link for where i can search for these drivers? i am assuming its VID_0664 and PID_0309 going of this picture? http://i248.photobucket.com/albums/gg195/craig2d/Capture.png

Comment: @CraigMatchett I don't know if there even are any, if you can get the VID and PID I can attempt to help.

Comment: VID_0664 and PID_0309

Comment: @CraigMatchett Unfortunately that's just a generic driver as well, I can't see any obvious replacement. I've just updated my answer with some other suggestions for you, but I'm afraid I'm out of ideas beyond physically trying to rotate the panel overlay.

Comment: i tried that mouse reverse program and it just flipped my mouse, it had no effect on my touch screen :( i also tried the calibration tool and that didnt work either. thanks for you help and suggestions anyway, i'll have to keep looking i guess

Comment: only other thing i can think of is because my monitor just says generic PnP monitor... do you think that could effect it? but i cant find any drivers to sort that out either

Comment: @CraigMatchett No, that'll be handling the visual aspect of your monitor, but your touchscreen will have it's own controller completely separate to the screen (even if it were like that from manufacture, the controllers are independant).

Answer (score 0):

[MAFMouse](http://www.maf-soft.de/mafmouse/) is a low level filter driver to rotate or invert mouse movements and some touch screens. Please contact me (I'm the author) for a demo version.