# Is there a way to rotate mouse movement with 45 degrees to the right?

Tags: windows, mouse, cursor

Recently I got an ergonomic mouse (Delux M618 [https://www.amazon.com/Delux-M618LU-Vertical-Ergonomic-Comfort/dp/B00D19KF7U](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00D19KF7U)). Trouble is due to the shape, the way my hand feels most comfortable holding it makes the mouse cursor go diagonally when I move the mouse up-down.

I've found a mouse direction altering solution however they strictly invert the axis; ex: [How can I reverse mouse movement (X & Y axis) system-wide? (Win 7 x64)](https://superuser.com/questions/406502/how-can-i-reverse-mouse-movement-x-y-axis-system-wide-win-7-x64) - this also doesn't work with multiple monitors which is a critical issue

Does anyone know a way to adjust mouse movement by angle?

Running on Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.maf-soft.de/mafmouse/
I heard they have a beta out that supports free rotation.

Comment: I'm the author of mafmouse - free rotation is not yet ready, but can be done. Please request it by email.