# Mouse pointer going in the opposite direction in Windows 11 and Ubuntu with multiple wireless mice

Tags: mouse, wireless-mouse, axis

I am having trouble with a wireless mouse. The mouse cursor started moving in the opposite direction: If I move the mouse up, pointer goes down, if I move left it goes right and so on. However, with a second mouse that I had here, everything was working normally.

Now, both mice are having the same problem. I tested the mouse on another computer with a different operating system, Ubuntu Latitude, and the problem occurs there as well. I tested on 2 laptops and a desktop and the inversion problem occurs on all of them.

In Windows, I found a workaround using SakasaMouse, a software that reverses the axes. But when I open a game, the axes become inverted again, since SakasaMouse does not work in games.

What worries me the most is that initially, only one mouse had a problem. Then, a second mouse had the same problem. Did Windows send something to the mouse? I am connecting to another computer now, and it already seems to be a problem with the hardware of both mice. This worries me when buying a new mouse and having the same problem.

I usually use Barrier to control multiple devices with the same mouse and keyboard. But now, because of this inversion, I can no longer do this since SakasaMouse does not work on multiple screens.

Out of curiosity, everything works normally with the touchpad, so when I use SakasaMouse, the touchpad is the one that starts having problems.

I have already reset the settings, uninstalled the mouse, updated the driver, and followed several tutorial videos, but nothing has solved the problem. Interestingly, some people on Reddit were able to solve a similar problem by resetting the device, but it seems to have worked only for [HV-MS733](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/kry9tp/mouse_axis_is_inverted_left_is_right_and_up_is/) or [KNUP KP V43](https://youtu.be/2U4vTHF8v1E), as shown in a video I found on YouTube.

This mouse reset function is only available in the software of these mice I mentioned above, but my mice are simple, one is CAERUS and the other is MO295 from Multilaser, both with their own USB connector and without their own software. Is there any way I can simulate this and force a reset inside the mice?

I believe that something is affecting the dongle, is there any generic firmware update to the dongle?

Comment: That is certainly a new one. Mouse drivers not set up properly?

Comment: @John I updated all drivers, but I'm not sure, but in 3 differente computers, Windows 10, 11 and Ubuntu the same issue occurs. What is weird is that the second mouse started to have the same issue.

Comment: I have an Ubuntu machine and a Kali machine here running alongside Windows with a LogiTech BT mouse and direction is correct and consistent. So I do not know. I have not seen this before.

Comment: Either set `xinput set-prop 14 311 -1 1 1` on Ubuntu, or turn off natural scrolling. See also https://en.naneedigital.com/article/how_to_reverse_the_mouse_scrolling_direction_in_ubuntu_aka_natural_scrolling

Comment: But in my case is not scrolling. It is the pointer, if I move mouse to right it goes to left, if I move up it goes down, and so on. The scroll works fine.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/406502/how-can-i-reverse-mouse-movement-x-y-axis-system-wide-win-7-x64

Comment: Since this appears to be a problem with the mouse itself (not with Windows or a specific PC), your best bet would be to contact the makers’ support.

Comment: On Ubuntu it worked with `xinput set-prop 11 "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" -1 0 1 0 -1 1 0 0` 1 that @DrMoishePippik suggested. And it is even better than Windows, because it only changed the id 11 which is my wireless mouse and both Touchpad and Mouse are working properly. I just buyed a new mouse it should be here in 10 days, I expect the new one works properly.